# Android accessability highlight

Tags: android

I want to highlight all the accessability clickable objects on screen. For this i create an app with an always on top layout.

```
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);


    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            720, 1280,
            0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    mWindowManager.addView(testDrawView, params);
```

I also create an accessability service, in order to take all the accessability clickable elements box parameters. It works and the output is printed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybfrC.png)

But the problem is that it doesnt update. When i do something on screen (all touches go through), i need the highlights of old elements to be deleted, and the higlight of new elements to be displayed. But changes do not update dynamycally, I need to open my app to force drawer to run.

I tried

```
    class BrRec extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        mHeadLayer.rects.clear();
        mHeadLayer.rects = (ArrayList<Rect>) intent.getSerializableExtra("rects");


        for (int i = 0; i < mHeadLayer.rects.size(); ++i)
        {
            mHeadLayer.invalidate(mHeadLayer.rects.get(i));
        }

        mHeadLayer.invalidate();}}
```

But it doesnt work.

Is there a way to dynamically highlight screen objects? I want to redraw my always on top view, even when it is not active.

Maybe activate it somehow programatically?